# Create a scheduler to re-compile stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am facing an issue on SQL Server in which my stored procedure becomes slow after couple of days.

I came to know that recompiling the stored procedure will work. However, I do not want to recompile that stored procedure every time it gets called.

Is it a good way to create a job on SQL Server which will execute following statement?

```
EXEC sp_recompile N'SP_NAME';
```

Will this cause any performance issues?

Below is my SP Structure.

```
@START_VALUE int=null,
@END_VALUE int=null`enter code here`
@UID NVARCHAR(MAX)=null,
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT   dbo.TABLE1.ID, 
              ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY TABLE1.UPDATED_ON desc) AS RN,   
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dbo.TABLE1.DATE, 101) AS TDATE,
              CATEGORY
              =(
                SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN1 FROM TABLE5 CT1 WHERE 
                 TABLE1.CATEGORY = CT1.CATEGORY_ID
              )
              , 
             TYPETEXT
             =(
                SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN1 FROM TABLE6 CT1 WHERE 
                 TABLE1.TYPE = CT1.TYPE_ID
             ),
              IMAGE = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(pm.C1 AS varchar(12))
                FROM TABLE2 pm WHERE
                pm.ID = TABLE1.ID AND pm.C1 IS NOT NULL AND pm.C1 <> '' 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )INTO #tempRecords       
            FROM         dbo.TABLE1 
                    WHERE 
                  ((@UID is null OR  dbo.TABLE1.ID = @UID )
            ORDER BY TABLE1.UPDATED DESC      

         SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #tempRecords;
        SELECT *,CONVERT([int],@count) AS 'TOTAL_RECORDS' FROM #tempRecords 
        WHERE #tempRecords.RN BETWEEN CONVERT([bigint],@START_VALUE) AND CONVERT([bigint],@END_VALUE)      


END

GO
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the procedure. Doing a scheduled recompile is fixing the symptom, not the cause. Can you post the procedure so we can help you fix it?

Comment: Please check this article from Paul White.You can use Option(recompile) on specific statement which has issues rather than recompiling stored procedure everytime..http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s I did not knew about this prefix issue, does it happens only for "sp_" or also for just "sp" ? My stored procedures all have this prefix, like for example spDoStuff. Will this be affected to or only if I would name it sp_DoStuff ?

Comment: @GuidoG: ***only*** `sp_` - nothing else

Comment: OK I got lucky then

Comment: Sean Lange is right. I would start with looking at the query plans. Get the plan when its fast and the plan for when it is slow and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

At very first: Replace Sub-Queries in the `SELECT` statement by Sub-Queries in `FROM` clause.

Here are some options to resolve 'slowing':
1. If procedure is executed not frequently try to use `RECOMPILE` option.
2. Look at statistics. Maybe it would be easier to `UPDATE STATISTICS` then recompile SP.
3. If statistics are the problem, you may try to use filtered statistics.
4. If none of these options works, you can just delete query plan for that procedure in automated manner from Query Cache and procedure will be daily recompiled itself.

However, at first, rebuild the main query.